# We are travelling to Hanover from Munich. Is transit in terminal 1 or terminal 2

Tags: transit, connecting-flights, airport-terminals, muc

We are travelling from Australia to Munich and then to Hanover.  Is transit in Terminal 1 or Terminal 2?

Comment: Have you already tried to look it up yourself (airport website, airline info etc)? No? Why?

Comment: There are no direct flights from Australia to Munich.

Comment: @Hilmar Is your comment indirectly trying to ask the OP for the full itinerary to determine whether the flight into MUC is domestic/EU or international?

Answer (score 1):

Your Hannover flight is on Lufthansa (I assume). They fly from Terminal 2.

Where you arrive depens on which airline you're coming in on. If it's a Star Alliance member, then it will also be terminal 2.